# What was the Tinker's message to the Dragon Reborn?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In Book 6 of the Wheel of Time, "The Lord of Chaos", the Band of the Red Hand came across a massacred caravan of Tinkers. One of the victims had scrawled a message:

> Fire had taken most of the wagon lying on its side, but the wagon bed
>   survived, propped on yellow wheels with red spokes. A man in a coat
>   that still showed a little eye-wrenching blue lay hard against it, one
>   sprawled hand black with blood. What he had written in shaky, letters
>   stood out darker than the wood of the wagon bottom.
>
> TELL THE DRAGON REBORN
>
> Tell him *what*? Mat thought. That somebody had killed a whole caravan
>   of Tinkers?

As far as I know, that question was never answered. **Who were these Tinkers, and what was the message supposed to convey?**

Comment: That Soylent Green is people.

Comment: Calling on my memory of the entire series, but sure this is answerable...

Comment: The best theory I can come up with would be that it was Shaido's doing, after the origin of Aiel was revealed. Few others have any reason to attack Tinkers.